# Firebase REST API auth not working with React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

Basically a friend and I have been working on our React project and we're using Redux and Redux Thunk on the backend to handle authentication. However, we seem to have ran into an issue. Our request was working before, but now it issues a Fetch Failed Loading: POST, and doesn't continue past the initial call. However, when checking Firebase, it returns the correctly created user. I know it doesn't go past the fetch because the console.log doesn't work at all.

```
export const signup = (email, password) => {


return async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API-KEY]',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
            returnSecureToken: true 
        })
    }
    );


    console.log(response);
```

Comment: Can you give us the complete error message ?

Answer (score 0):

If async is used, 
it is recommended to use try{do await something...}catch(e){} format to write.

```
try{
    do await something
 }catch(e){
    error something
}
```

Easy to catch errors

Comment: It doesn't catch anything :/ I execute a catch (e) and console log the e, but get nothing in return.

Answer (score 0):

If async is used in the fetch. Need to do this

```
let response = await fetch(You_URL)
let json = await response.json()
```

After the response object is obtained,
it needs an await to get the body content from the response
The link below has instructions
Address： [Here is the description](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-arraybuffer)

Comment: This also doesn't work unfortunately :(. Like I mentioned prior, this snippet of code was working perfectly for the first 10 authentications, but now has stopped working completely

Comment: I haven't encountered this situation for the time being, sorry, I couldn't help you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fetch API, you need to do `await` again

```js
export const signup = (email, password) => {


return async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API-KEY]',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
            returnSecureToken: true 
        })
    }
    );

const data = await response.json();

console.log(data );
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise